# How to delete (with .bat) files with different extensions in one line?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .bat (to execute in Windows only) that deletes some files with specific extensions (malware).

Example:

```
if exist *.lnk del /f *.lnk
if exist *.inf del /f *.inf
if exist *.init del /f *.init
if exist *.ini del /f *.ini
if exist *.FAT del /f *.FAT
etc etc (a very long list)
```

How can I delete all these files in one line only?

Comment: I assume this is only within a specific directory? Because many of these extensions are perfectly legitimate in general.

Comment: I certainly hope so; if he deletes .inf files from the wrong directory, he's gonna have a bad time. Really, he should look into antimalware software instead of just making assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can write:

```
del /f *.lnk *.inf *.init *.ini *.fat
```

I'm not sure why you had `if exist` in there, but if it is just to suppress output in case there are no files, then you can redirect to null output:

```
del /f *.lnk *.inf *.init *.ini *.fat 2>NUL
```